# A Resourcefile that isn't translated

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I am building an application in wpf, and I am using the translation system with the resource files.

So I have the following resource files:

- `Resources.resx`
- `Resources.nl.resx`
- `Resources.fr.resx`

I want to add something like a `resource.global.resx` if it excists that **contains global strings that doesn't need to be translated.** This could contain things like aplication names (paint, word,...) and other stuff I use.

**Is this possible? and how?**

Comment: Just keep them in `Resources.resx`, no? I don't remember it well and can't check it now, but as far as I do, your general resource file already provides you with this functionality.

Comment: I will test this later on this day :)

Comment: did you check it? It should work. If the strings are missing in the resource of your current locale, the app should fall back to Resources.resx

Comment: Yea it works, but i choose for making a seperate file, for seperation of concerns

Comment: ah, good.
6 more symbols to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that you can just add a resources.global.resx and you need to actually change the code so that it goes to the global file (resources_global.test1).